# Dynamic Programming problems with an additional condition besides the value that must be calculated

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

Say I have a weighted graph where the weights represent distance (in miles). I am to find the shortest path from some vertex S to some vertex T. Further, say there is a monetary cost  associated with each vertex. Now, at the beginning I have $M (i.e. M dollars). My job is to find the shortest path without incurring any debt.

My Attempt:

I use Dijkstra's algorithm, but my solution only works in some instances but not all. Does anyone know how to solve this so it works -- NO SIMPLEX, please, unless you implement it fully. A java working code is much appreciated. I already looked at the `Upper-Intermediate` example on [top-coders](http://www.topcoder.com/tc?d1=tutorials&d2=dynProg&module=Static) but I don't know how to implement their pseudo-code.

I try many different code/approaches but all of them have too many bugs. My tries are too numerous to post and posting just one does not make much sense.

Comment: edited to add more tags. Reader, please suggest relevant tags. Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @ Ravi Gupta, it is not at all clear what you mean. I provide a test case (the `main` method) and mention that it works for `s=0 and t=7` but not for `s=0 and t=9`; just play with the starting amount of `money`. If you draw the adjacency matrix as a graph on a piece of paper, maybe that will help. In addition, I provide a link to a top-coder example. Just scroll down to the section `Upper-Intermediate`. Maybe you can implement their pseudo-code in Java. Thanks.

Comment: If there is a positive monetary cost associated with each vertex, it is impossible to go anywhere without incurring debts. Or are there vertices whose associated cost is zero? Or you just want to minimize a combination of miles and dollars?

Comment: @Vitalij Zadneprovskij, I am starting out with `M` dollars. I am to find the shortest distance without exceeding my budget of `M` dollars.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to say that Dijkstra's algorithm works only in some cases, because it picks just the edges that cost less, while you have to verify the existence of two conditions:

- the total cost of the path in dollars is within the bugdet of `M` dollars;
- the number of miles is minimum.

An approach that is guranteed to be correct, but could be really slow to run is this. You make two steps:

- find all the possible paths in terms of cost in dollars and put them into an array or a list;
- for each path calculate the number of miles and pick the path or the paths that have the minimum number of miles.

The problem with this approach is that the list produced could be really big. So maybe there is a better way to solve this problem.